# How to display the values of the numbers in T-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called 'name' type char, how do print the values ​​in the names of which there is at least one digit / at least three digits / exactly five digits? for example:

```
Name
-----------
'name1'
'name2356'
'name12567'
```

1. at least one digit will return `'name1', 'name2356' and 'name12567'`
2. at least three digits will return `'name2356' and 'name12567'`
3. exactly five digit will return `'name12567'`

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: Do you mean when the column contains given number of digits within the string? The following http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx will help you

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[udf_CountNumericCharacters](@strText VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '')
    END
    RETURN LEN(@strText)
END

-- Greater than one
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE dbo.[udf_CountNumericCharacters]([Name]) > 1

-- Greater than three
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE dbo.[udf_CountNumericCharacters]([Name]) > 3

-- Exactly 5
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE dbo.[udf_CountNumericCharacters]([Name]) = 5
```

A quick search will get you a million different ways to print these results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UDF

```
create function dbo.HasDigits(@Text VarChar(80), @Digits int)
returns bit 
as
begin
   declare @i int = datalength(@text)
   while @i>=1 and @digits>0 begin
     if ISNUMERIC(substring(@text,@i,1))=1 
  set @digits=@digits-1
     else 
  set @i = 1
     set @i=@i - 1
   end

  return case when @digits>0 then 0 else 1 end
end
```

To use it, execute

```
select * from MyTable where dbo.HasDigits(Name,3) = 1
```